# obtener array de respuesta con Ajax jQuery y mandar mensaje en caso de error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un par de dudas con AJAX. Estoy tratando de guardar los datos de un formulario y quiero retornar una respuesta la cual estoy instanciando en mi metodo ajax y construyendo en la query del DAO para ser devuelta como log.

Aquí pueden ver mi formdata y mi ajax:

```
var infoEmpleado = new FormData();

var nombre = $('input[name="nombre"]').val();
var apellidos = $('input[name="apellidos"]').val();
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
var accion = $('input[name="accion"]').val();

infoEmpleado.append('nombre', nombre);
infoEmpleado.append('apellidos', apellidos);
infoEmpleado.append('email', email);
infoEmpleado.append('accion', accion);

$.ajax({
  url: '../controller/empleadoControlador.php',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  data: infoEmpleado,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (respuesta.respuesta == 'correcto') {
      Swal.fire({
        position: 'center',
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Alta completada',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
      })
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("../index.php");
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'ID o password incorrecto',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
      })
  }
}


 });
```

Aquí tengo el controlador que recibe los datos para mandarlos al DAO:

```
if ($_POST['accion'] == 'crearEmpleado') {

        $empleado = new Empleado();
        $empDao = new EmpleadoDAO();
        $nombre = $empleado->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos = $empleado->setApellidos($_POST['apellidos']);
        $email = $empleado->setEmail($_POST['email']);
        $empDao->insertarEmpleado($empleado);

}
```

Y aquí el DAO que lo recibe y donde he decidido construir la respuesta:

```
public function insertarEmpleado($empleado)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO empleado (nombre, apellidos, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $empleado->getNombre());
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $empleado->getApellidos());
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $empleado->getEmail());
    $resultadoRegistro = $stmt->execute();
    if ($resultadoRegistro) {
          $respuesta = array(
              'respuesta' => 'correcto',
              'datosEmpleado' => array(
                'nombre' => $empleado->getNombre(),
                'apellidos' => $empleado->getApellidos(),
                'email' => $empleado->getEmail(),
              )
          );
          echo json_encode($respuesta);
        return $this->db->lastInsertId();
    } else {
      $respuesta = array(
          'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
      echo json_encode($respuesta);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

La consola me retorna esto:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (app.js:97)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

No sé cómo hacerlo y la documentación no la entiendo. Necesito que me lo expliquen como si fuera tonto por favor.

Comment: En cuanto la 1ª duda: en esta parte `success: function(respuesta) {` el parámetro `respuesta` representa, como su nombre bien indica, la respuesta del servidor, o sea, todo lo que sale por pantalla desde el servidor, si la petición tuvo éxito (success).  Eso no tiene nada que ver con lo mandaste en `data`, que es lo que recibe el servidor en `$_POST`.  En cuanto a la 2ª duda: eso depende de lo que ocurra en tu archivo `controladorModelo.php`. Debes seguir el flujo del mismo, depurando las variables que maneje, para determinar por qué siempre termina diciendo que ha guardado con éxito.

Comment: No puedes hacer un `JSON.parse` sin antes comprobar que el servidor responde siempre un JSON. Debes escribir un código coherente. Esto no tiene sentido: `return $this->db->lastInsertId();` por lo tanto comenta esa línea. Esto tampoco tiene sentido: `return -1;` comenta también esa línea y prueba. Al poner esos `return` puede que te estén fastidiando el JSON. Y prueba la respuesta haciendo un `console.log(xhr.responseText);` directamente. No es cuestión de volverse loco, sino de aprender  a depurar, a probar qué hay en los datos, ¿me explico?

Comment: Sí, gracias a ti he llegado a la conclusión de que mi problema es que no sé depurar. Te lo agradezco muchísimo porque me pondré las pilas en ese sentido.

Comment: He comentado los return y he hecho el log del xhr.responsetext pero está vacío, no undefined, sino vacío. En la consola sale la línea pero no pone nada...

Comment: entiendo que esto está pasando porque creo el objeto xhr pero está vacío. Debería hacer un xhr.open(url), luego un xhr.onload y así ya tendría un xhr.responsetext con valor? esto funciona con javascript puro pero no sé si con ajax jquery es lo más correcto...

Comment: OK espera, es que no me había fijado que estas implementando `XMLHttpRequest`. Eso no es necesario, pues estás usando Ajax de jQuery que ya lo hace. Comenta esta línea: `// const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` también esta: `// const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` y pon el `if`así: **`if (data.respuesta == 'correcto') {`**  de paso haz un `console.log(data);` como ya dije en mi respuesta, los datos que manda el servidor estarán en `data`. No sé por qué te estás liando con `XMLHttpRequest`, eso es para cuando no usas jQuery.

Comment: OK, XMLHttpRequest olvidado. El console.log(data) me devuelve el html de la vista correspondiente a la lista de usuarios existentes. No entiendo por qué si en data: infoempleado, yo estoy pasando un formData. Gracias por las molestias que te sigues tomando.

Comment: Estoy probando a pasar los siguientes argumentos: `success: function(response, status, jqXHR)` al hacer log de ellas me devuelve lo siguiente:

Comment: el response está vacío (no undefined, es un string vacío), el status me devuelve success y el jqXHR me devuelve un objeto que no entiendo. Pero de ninguna manera consigo acceder a la respuesta construida en el DAO para saber si es 'correcto'.

Comment: En el ante penúltimo comentario ibas por buen camino y en el último empiezas a liarte de nuevo. Como ya he dicho tres o cuatro veces y como ya expliqué en la respuesta dada: los datos del servidor estarán en el parámetro `data` del `success`. Si no retienes esa idea te vas a perder inventando cosas. Si como dices en el ante penúltimo comentario en el log lo que ves es el HTML de la vista es porque eso es lo que muestra la URL a la que diriges la petición.

Comment: Es que eso es lo que no entiendo. Yo estoy dirigiendo la petición a mi controlador. En este controlador pretendo recoger todo lo que viene del formData y mandarlo a mi DAO donde creo la respuesta en forma de json para que la saque por el log. 
No entiendo que pinta ahí la vista de los usuarios y tampoco logro dar con la solución.

Comment: Si te sale eso es porque el controlador u otro código que llamas o incluyes muestra eso. Depurarlo es muy fácil, sólo tienes que seguir el flujo del código paso a paso, qué archivos se incluyen, qué métodos son llamados, etc... así encontrarás en qué punto está apareciendo ese contenido HTML. Es cuestión de conocer y controlar tu código.

Comment: Vale, he dado con ello. He conseguido que funcione haciendo un serialize() de los datos del formulario. El problema era que ni siquiera entraba en la condición del controlador `if ($_POST['accion'] == 'crearEmpleado')` porque el post contenía un array rarísimo:

Comment: `array(1) {
  ["------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(888) "
  
------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nombre"

Jorge
------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="apellidos"

apellidodeejemplo
------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

email@gmail.com

------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="accion"

crearEmpleado
------WebKitFormBoundary3IAsuhMZxtUOXfKQ--
"
}`

Comment: Lo que muestras es un `header` que contiene la petición y los datos. `FormData` sirve generalmente para operaciones complejas como enviar archivos adjuntos y cosas así, si es para mandar sólo datos como nombre, apellido, etc puedes prescindir de `FormData` y recoger los datos de forma simple con `serialize`. Y si el `form` tiene un `enctype multipart` debes quitárselo si no vas a adjuntar archivos. También convendría que revises ciertas configuraciones de Ajax como `contentType`, `processData` y `cache` . Puede que no necesites usar esas configuraciones para este caso.

Comment: También te recomiendo que revises las fuentes que usas para aprender y qué tipos de código usan. A veces un tipo de código es útil para unas cosas, pero no para otras.

Comment: Exacto!!! Estaba planteando otra duda ahora mismo e iba a redirigirla dese aquí como una nueva. El problema es que sí necesito subir una imagen y ni con formdata ni con serialize puedo hacerlo...

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto a tu **primera duda**,  la parte del `success` está bien explicada en la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> ### `success`
>
> Type: Function( Anything `data`, String `textStatus`, jqXHR `jqXHR` )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> ---
>
> ### `success`
>
> Tipo: Función (Cualquier cosa `data`, Cadena `textStatus`, jqXHR `jqXHR`)
>
> Una función que se llamará si la
>   solicitud tiene éxito. La función obtiene tres argumentos: **los datos
>   devueltos por el servidor**, formateados según el parámetro `dataType`
>   o la función de devolución de llamada `dataFilter`, si se especifica;
>   una cadena que describe el estado; y el objeto jqXHR (en jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest). A partir de jQuery 1.5, la configuración de `success`
>   puede aceptar una variedad de funciones. Cada función se llamará por
>   turno. Este es un evento Ajax.

Es decir, lo que hay en tu objeto `respuesta` **no tiene nada que ver con lo que mandaste al servidor, sino con lo que éste respondió**. Precisamente dices que *en la consola me pinta todo el código html con la lista de empleados guardados...*, porque lo que está respondiendo el servidor a tu petición es esa lista. Y si tu servidor sólo responde *Hola*, pues lo que tendrás en `respuesta` es *Hola*.

Lo que mandaste al servidor, en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax, el servidor lo recibió en `$_POST` y lo procesó para devolverte la respuesta que esperas. No tendría ningún sentido que el servidor responda con lo mismo que le mandaste. Aún así, si quieres de vuelta lo mismo que mandaste puedes responder con un `print_r($_POST);` y lo tendrías de vuelta.

En cuanto a tu **segunda duda**, podemos ver lo que dice la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) sobre la parte `error` de las peticiones Ajax:

> ### `error`
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR `jqXHR`, String `textStatus`, String
>   `errorThrown` )
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." (in HTTP/2 it may instead be an empty string) As of
>   jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each
>   function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for
>   cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax
>   Event.
>
> ---
>
> ### `error`
>
> Tipo: Función (jqXHR `jqXHR`, Cadena `textStatus`, Cadena
>   `errorThrown`)
>
> Una función que se llamará si la solicitud falla. La función recibe
>   tres argumentos: el objeto `jqXHR` (en jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest),
>   una cadena que describe el tipo de error que ocurrió y un objeto de
>   excepción opcional, si ocurrió uno. Los valores posibles para el
>   segundo argumento (además de nulo) son "`timeout`", "`error`",
>   "`abort`" y "`parsererror`". Cuando se produce un error HTTP,
>   `errorThrown` recibe la parte textual del estado HTTP, como "No
>   encontrado" o "Error interno del servidor". (en HTTP / 2 puede ser una
>   cadena vacía) A partir de jQuery 1.5, la configuración de error puede
>   aceptar una serie de funciones. Cada función se llamará por turno.
>   **Nota**: No se llama a este controlador para las solicitudes JSONP entre dominios y las secuencias de comandos entre dominios. Este es un
>   evento Ajax.

En tu segunda duda dices que no entiendes por qué, tratando de provocar un error en el controlador, nunca entra en la parte de error. Hay que entender que esta parte de `error` es **para controlar errores reales, no errores de lógica** en tu código. Para probarla basta con que provoques un error de servidor en tu controlador. Si provocas por ejemplo un error 500, cometiendo a propósito un error de sintaxis en tu controlador, o un error 4040 dirigiendo la petición a una URL que no existe, etc.

**Los errores de lógica tendrían que ser controlados también en el `success`**. Supongamos que mandas a buscar los datos de un empleado y éste no existe. Entonces desde el servidor podrías responder con un JSON que contenga la clave `error` (en ese caso tienes que indicarlo en el `dataType`)  Pero el código no entrará en la parte `error` de Ajax que es una cosa distinta. Realmente la petición funcionó, en el sentido de que no hubo ningún error de red o de servidor. Entonces para manejar ese error harías algo como esto:

**PHP:**

```
if (... hay datos ...){
    $mData= ... array con los datos 
} else {
    $mData=array ("error"=>"Esto es un error lógico: No se encontraron los datos");
}
echo json_encode($mData);
```

**JS:**

```
  success: function(respuesta) {
       if (respuesta.error) {
           console.log(respuesta.error);
           //Hacer lo que haya que hacer
       }else{
           //Se encontraron los datos que se pedían, mostrarlos aquí
       }
```

Comment: ok ya entendí. El problema es que quiero ver lo que estoy mandando porque a la hora de crear un registro, lo hace bien, pero cuando  lo actualizo, no lo hace. Con lo que me has dicho del print post podré sacarlo. Gracias!!

Comment: El problema sigue estando en el error. He editado mi publicación para que veas que lo he puesto como tú me has dicho. Aún así, sigo teniendo el mismo problema...

Comment: @InfiniteRoads, el que en este bloque `success: function(respuesta) {` declares el parámetro como `response` o como `data` es indiferente. Como ya expliqué, ese objeto no tiene que ver con el parámetro `data` que pasas al servidor en la petición Ajax. Si no lo puedes resolver verifica con un `console.log` lo que está respondiendo el servidor y si quieres agrégalo a la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor. Y muestra también cómo estás trabajando en el servidor para poder escribir el código conforme a esa lógica.

Comment: Sigo volviéndome loco con esto. Edito pregunta principal.

Answer (score 0):

**Data** ya está definido

```
  data: infoEmpleado,
```

Deberías utilizar otro nombre para el paŕametro.

```
success: function(response)
```

**Comprobar el error**

```
if (data.error) {
  console.log('Hubo un error');
}
```

Tu código espera la entrada **error** dentro de tu respuesta, pero no la encuentra porque estás dando una respuesta JSON de parte del servidor, en todo caso sería

```
response["error"]
```